# Установка default значения для поля модели типа ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-orm

Здраствуйте, вот модель для иллюстрации:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField(max_length=10)

def get_foo():
    return Foo.objects.get_or_create(name='Russian',
                                         currency_code='RUB',
                                         is_main_currency=True,
                                         is_active=True,
                                         currency_icon_class='fa-rub')[0]

class Bar(models.Model):
    b = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    a = models.ForeignKey(Foo, default=get_foo)
```

Нужно назначить для поля "a" класса "Bar" значение по умолчанию в виде функции которая будет либо создавать либо получать значение по умолчанию модели Foo. Проблема в том, что при подготовке миграций, и последующем их применении - выдается ошибка что модели Foo не существует в БД. Требуется не хардкодить первичный ключ в значение default, а именно получать актуальный.

Такая схема моделей работает, если обработать исключение в методе создания/получения объекта foo. Но это выглядит костыльно:

```
def get_foo():
    try:
        return Foo.objects.get_or_create(name='Russian',
                                         currency_code='RUB',
                                         is_main_currency=True,
                                         is_active=True,
                                         currency_icon_class='fa-rub')[0]
    except Exeption:
        return 1
```

На английском stackoverflow находил похожие вопросы, но однозначного ответа кроме хардкода значения, или переопределения метода save не нашел (при переопределении метода save также возникает ряд противоречий). Подскажите,пожалуйста, может кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой ситуацией, как грамотно настроить получение default значения для поля модели ForeignKey? В реальном проекте используется абстрактный класс, но это не влияет на результат.

Comment: Получилось ли решить задачу?

Comment: @AndrewHolovko Сделали так:  def get_default_currency():
    """Получение дефолтного значения Валюты для Миксина Локализации"""
    try:
        return Currency.get_default()
    except django.db.Error:
        return LocaleMixin.DEFAULT_CURRENCY, где DEFAULT_CURRENCY - константа в модели LocaleMixin, равна 1. Я так понял, для django нету какойто-то красивой схемы получения значения по умолчанию для поля модели с внешним ключем.

Comment: Помог ли мой ответ?

Comment: @AndrewHolovko вы подтвердили мою теорию, мое решение получилось схожим с вашим способом переопределния метода save. Так что да, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый вариант - можно переопределить метод save. Если значения `a` - нету, мы достаём из БД (или любой вашей логикой) значение и присваиваем его.

```
class Bar(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(Foo, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.a
        except:
            self.a = Foo.objects.first()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Второй вариант присваивать default значение.

```
class Bar(models.Model):
    ...
    a = models.ForeignKey(Foo, default=1)
```

Третий вариант установить его сразу после записи, при условии, что у него `blank = True`